# While loop with String comparing isn't working?

Tags: java, string, compare

I just started learning Java... Sorry if this is just a way too dumb question.

I was trying to compare the user input. If the input is not either "Yes" or "No" then force the user to input either one of them... but my code don't work...

Compiling has no issue, but even if the input is "Yes" or "No" the while loop just keep looping.

Tried printing out the value of "userInput" within the loop but it shows "Yes" or "No" correctly when inputted, yet the loop just goes on.

```
protected static boolean askUser() {
        String userInput = "x";
        boolean userChoice;
        System.out.println("Do you have a question you want to know the answer too? (Yes/No): ");
        userInput = input.nextLine();

        while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            System.out.println("Please input only \"Yes\" or \"No\": ");
            userInput = input.nextLine();
        }

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            userChoice = true;
        } else {
            userChoice = false;
        }

        return userChoice;
    }
```

Any idea on how to fix this code?

Comment: check do-while loop

Comment: `!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("No")` is always true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("No")` is always true because `Yes` is not `No` and `No` is not `Yes`.

You will want to loop while the input is not `Yes` **and** not `No`, so the condition should be `!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") && !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("No")`.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much!
Dang I do need more practice. lol